# When selecting a product variation attribute, the add to cart button and attribute disappear

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a strange issue.
I have created product dislays with product variations, which have attributes (size, color etc)

The attributes field show up fine on the product display, but when one of the product attributes is clicked, the Add to cart button and attribute field disappears! The rest of the product variation is display correctly.

My first thought is that it is caused by a Ajax issue since the clicking of the product shows a rotating ajax loader.

Sorry I have no idea where to start debugging. The console does not give error message.

Comment: For the field you defined  for those attributes, how did you define that field regarding how many values are allowed (is it "unlimited", or is it just "1")?